# Is it possible to test crystal reports using QTP?

Tags: automated-testing

Can QTP be used to test reports generated on Crystal Reports Server?

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. You could potentially create an extensibility plugin for it though, to provide the functionality that you would need. See the QTP help for more info on extensibility plugins to see if that sounds feasible or not. It requires quite a bit of extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

no it cant automate crystal reports.